# Bash - How to skip a column while writing to csv

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv, scripting

In the following screenshot as you can see on the first row, there are country codes and for each country code with have two different related columns (MT & MO). how do I skip adding a empty column after each country using bash script?

[image]

Here is how I write the countries row:

```
echo "'SG',,'ID',,'AU',,'MY',," >> ${fileName}
```

as you can see there are ,, in between the country codes to facilitate the reading the output but is there any way to skip adding column to end up having the whole column for each country? I need something like this:

[image]

Please advice,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSV format does not provide any way to indicate that a cell spans several columns.  In fact, it doesn't provide any way to indicate formatting of any kind.

So if you are restricted to using CSV, you cannot do better than inserting an empty cell.